# Woocommerce API connection to place order button

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I am trying to connect to an api using the code below, so when the customer clicks on the "place order" button on the Woocommerce checkout page, I am getting a *"please try again"* error:

```
var amount = <?php global $woocommerce; print WC()->cart->total; ?>;
var merchantOrderId = '<?php echo print time(); ?>';
var apiKey = 'm85BXXLpf_icrSvqbElR11xquEgmKZ8wfeRb2ly3-G7pIwCKDuytgplB7AQGi-5t';

renderMMoneyPaymentButton(amount, merchantOrderId, apiKey);
```

I am trying to pass this information to the api via this function but I am not getting a successful connection.

```
public function process_payment( $order_id ) {

    global $woocommerce;

    // we need it to get any order detailes
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);


    /*
     * Array with parameters for API interaction
     */
    $args = array(
     'amount' => '<?php global $woocommerce; print WC()->cart->total; ?>',
     'merchant_order_id' => '<?php print time(); ?>',
     'api_Key' => 'm85BXXLpf_icrSvqbElR11xquEgmKZ8wfeRb2ly3-G7pIwCKDuytgplB7AQGi-5t',
     'currency' => 'BBD',

    );
    /*
     * Your API interaction could be built with wp_remote_post()
     */
     $response = wp_remote_post( 'https://api.mmoneybb.com/merchant/js/mmoney-payment.js', $args );


     if( !is_wp_error( $response ) ) {

         $body = json_decode( $response['body'], true );

         // it could be different depending on your payment processor
         if ( $body ['$response'] == 'APPROVED') {

            // we received the payment
            $order->payment_complete();
            $order->reduce_order_stock();

            // some notes to customer (replace true with false to make it private)
            $order->add_order_note( 'Thanks for your payment!!!!', true );

            // Empty cart
            $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

            // Redirect to the thank you page
            return array(
                'result' => 'success',
                'redirect' => $this->get_return_url( $order )
            );

         } else {
            wc_add_notice(  'Please try again.', 'error' );
            return;
        }

    } else {
        wc_add_notice(  'Connection error.', 'error' );
        return;
    }

}
```

let me know what i am doing wrong much appreciated also this is the other script as well

```
 function renderMMoneyPaymentButton(amount, merchantOrderId, apiKey) {
  let paymentParams = {
    amount: amount,
    api_key: apiKey,
    currency: 'BBD',
    merchant_order_id: merchantOrderId,
    onCancel: function () { console.log('Modal closed'); },
    onError: function(error) { console.log('Error', error); },
    onPaid: function (invoice) { console.log('Payment complete', invoice); }
  };

  // "mMoney" window global provided by sourcing mmoney-payment.js script.
  // Attach the button to the empty element.
  mMoney.payment.button.render(paymentParams, '#mmoney-payment-button');


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In your first snippet code you are using javascript and you need to get the **order Id** and then the **order total**… You can only get the Order ID after the order is placed…

There is an answer example [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55189353/3730754).

2) Your 2nd public function involves only PHP… There are some errors and mistakes in this code. Try the following revisited code instead:

```
public function process_payment( $order_id ) {

    // Get The WC_Order Object instance
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    /*
     * Array with parameters for API interaction
     */
    $args = array(
        'amount'            => $order->get_total(),
        'merchant_order_id' => $order_id,
        'api_Key'           => 'm85BXXLpf_icrSvqbElR11xquEgmKZ8wfeRb2ly3-G7pIwCKDuytgplB7AQGi-5t',
        'currency'          => $order->get_currency(),
    );

    /*
     * Your API interaction could be built with wp_remote_post()
     */
     $response = wp_remote_post( 'https://api.mmoneybb.com/merchant/js/mmoney-payment.js', $args );

     if( !is_wp_error( $response ) ) {

         $body = json_decode( $response['body'], true );

         // it could be different depending on your payment processor
         if ( $body ['$response'] == 'APPROVED') {

            // we received the payment
            $order->payment_complete();
            $order->reduce_order_stock();

            // some notes to customer (replace true with false to make it private)
            $order->add_order_note( 'Thanks for your payment!!!!', true );

            // Empty cart
            $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

            // Redirect to the thank you page
            return array(
                'result' => 'success',
                'redirect' => $this->get_return_url( $order )
            );

         } else {
            wc_add_notice(  'Please try again.', 'error' );
            return;
        }

    } else {
        wc_add_notice(  'Connection error.', 'error' );
        return;
    }

}
```

It should better work.

Comment: Thanks for your help posted antoher question at and posted plugin code for further clarity will donate to you page fo r your help much appreciated.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55198697/custom-woocommerce-payment-gateway